# Using checkboxes values in SQL "IN"-operator

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have a form with several checkboxes in it. Values of ticking checkboxes are used after in the SQL-query including in Excel-macro. I use these values in SQL "IN"-operator. So, everythig works. But I don't like the code for my macro.

For ticking checkboxes I use such code (and if there were more value the list would be very huge):

```
Public Location1 As String
Public Location2 As String
Public Location3 As String
Public Location4 As String

Private Sub OKCommandButton2_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Location1 = "LocationValue1"
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then Location2 = "LocationValue2"
If CheckBox3.Value = True Then Location3 = "LocationValue3"
If CheckBox4.Value = True Then Location4 = "LocationValue4"
...
```

And for using it in SQl I use such code:

```
query = "SELECT Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4, 0, 0, Param5, 0 FROM Table1 " & _
"WHERE Param1 like'" & "%" & CraftDefinition.Craft & "%" & "'AND Param6>0 AND Param2 IN ('" & _
LocationDefinition.Location1 & "','" & LocationDefinition.Location2 & "','" & LocationDefinition.Location3 & "','" & _
LocationDefinition.Location4 & "')" & _
"ORDER BY Param2, Param3"
```

The question is: can I rewrite my code in more compact, laconic and sophisticated way? Maybe I should use another operator in SQL-part; maybe I can rewrite my VBA-part, for using only one parameter in SQl.

Thank you.

Comment: what is `LocationDefinition`?

Comment: It's a name of the form with note checkboxes.

Comment: I guessed it. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the "controls" Feature and write your Value into the "TAG" from the checkbox

```
Dim TB As Control
Dim ChkBoxString As String
ChkBoxString = "("

For Each TB In Me.Controls    
    If TypeOf TB Is CheckBox Then
        If TB.Value = True Then
            ChkBoxString = ChkBoxString & TB.Tag & ", "
        End If
    End If
Next TB
ChkBoxString = ChkBoxString & ")"
ChkBoxString = Replace(ChkBoxString, ", )", ")")
```

So you can use your Script:

```
  query = "SELECT Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4, 0, 0, Param5, 0 FROM Table1 " & _
"WHERE Param1 like'" & "%" & CraftDefinition.Craft & "%" & "'AND Param6>0 AND Param2 " _
IN " & ChkBoxString
```

Greets Ralf

Comment: Thank you for your solution.
Macro works with a few addings in your example.
1) I added a symbol " ' " where it is essential.
2) But the biggest problem was with the "If TypeOf Is CheckBox" - condition. This constrution works only if I put "MSForms." before "CheckBox".

Answer (score 0):

Create function that return string expression with comma delimited, and set the value in the Tag property of the checkbox

```
Function GetExpression() As String
Dim contr As Control
Dim comma  As String
Dim str As String
str = ""
For Each contr In UserForm1.Controls
  comma = IIf(str <> "", ",", "")
  If TypeName(contr) = "CheckBox" Then
    If contr.Value = True Then str = str + comma + contr.Tag
  End If
Next
GetExpression = str
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sub that "makes" the query (or build the query string) is called while the Userform is still loaded then you can code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Dim Locations As String '<--| UserForm scoped variable: all subs in the userform code pane can "see" it

Private Sub OKCommandButton2_Click()
    Dim ctrl As Control

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls '<--| loop through userform controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then '<--| consider only checkboxes
            If ctrl.value Then Locations = Locations & "LocationValue" & Mid(ctrl.Name, 9, Len(ctrl.Name) - 8) & "','" '<--| if checkbox is checked then update 'Location' string
        End If
    Next ctrl    
End Sub

Private Sub QuerySub() '<-- name of any Sub inside Userfom code pane that has to make the query
    Dim Query As String

    If Locations <> "" Then '<--| this Sub can "see" 'Locations' even if it has been initialized in a different Sub of the same Userform code pane
        Query = "SELECT Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4, 0, 0, Param5, 0 FROM Table1 " & _
        "WHERE Param1 like'" & "%" & CraftDefinition.Craft & "%" & "'AND Param6>0 AND Param2 IN ('" & _
        Left(Locations, Len(Locations) - 3) & "')" & _
        "ORDER BY Param2, Param3"
    Else
        ' code to handle 'Locations' empty string
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a tiny bit wrong because you get `IN ('', '', '', '')` when unchecked, but if you don't mind that, then maybe something like this:

```
locations$ = Mid$( _
    IIf(CheckBox1, "','LocationValue1", "") & _
    IIf(CheckBox2, "','LocationValue2", "") & _
    IIf(CheckBox3, "','LocationValue3", "") & _
    IIf(CheckBox4, "','LocationValue4", ""), 4) ' works even is all unchecked

query = " ... AND Param2 IN ('" & locations & "') ORDER BY Param2, Param3"
```

or if all of the values really start with "LocationValue" then

```
Locations$ = Mid$(Replace(IIf(CheckBox1, ",1", "") & _
    IIf(CheckBox2, ",2", "") & IIf(CheckBox3, ",3", "") & _
    IIf(CheckBox4, ",4", ""), ",", "','LocationValue"), 4)
```